# Undefined error with jquery while trying to parse json

Tags: php, jquery, json

Here is my json response:

```
[{"durum":"1"},{"durum":"2"},{"durum":"3"}]
```

My jquery function:

> ```
>       $("select#durum").change(function(){
>           $.post("autocomplete/ara_detay",{durum: $(this).val()}, function(j){
>               var events = j; 
>               var event = events[0];                  
>               alert(j.length);
>               alert(j.durum);
>               alert(j.durum);
>               var options = '';
>               for (var i = 0; i < j.length; i++) {
>                   options += '<option value="' + j[i].durum + '">' + j[i].durum + '</option>';
>               }
>               $("#durum").html(options);
>           })      })
> ```

j.length alert says "43" and other alert messages says "undefined".

In which part am i doing wrong ?

Comment: have you checked in the console what was actually in `j`? and BTW, you can't use `event` as a variable name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

j is a string

```
var jsonParsed = JSON.parse(j);
alert(jsonParsed[0].durum);
alert(jsonParsed[1].durum);
alert(jsonParsed[2].durum);
```